# date format in ms-access

Tags: ms-access, date-format

I am retiriving the datetime from the msaccess & willing to show it in the custom format so  do i get the data in that format.
the required format if `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: For the most part you should not need format on MS Access because the format os obtained from the computer locale. To format a date to dd/mm/yyyy is nearly always a sign of a deeper problem. It is quite likely that this is going to lead to more difficulties, for example, are you quite sure that what you think is a month Access also thinks is a month?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for this?

```
Format(Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

I'm using the current date (`Date`) as an example, but of course you can do that with any `Date` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try do this

```
Format(anyDate, dd/MM/yyyy)
```

For more information and format for date, you can clik [HERE](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php)